# how do you check if variable is equal in python

Tags: python

I have a line array that values in position 5 can be either of these values:

```
"Tablespace Free Space (MB)", "Tablespace Space Used (%)"
```

if `line[5]` is any of these I need to do some extra work.

I have tried this:

```
if (line[5] in ("Tablespace Space Used (%)")|("Tablespace Free Space (MB)"))

    # some other code here
```

I keep getting this error:

```
    if (line[5] in ("Tablespace Space Used (%)"|"Tablespace Free Space (MB)"))
                                                                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You are missing a `:` at the end of your line.

Comment: You need to add a ':' at the end of your if statement.  For example: `if (line[5] in ("Tablespace Space Used (%)", "Tablespace Free Space (MB)"):`

Comment: Also, relational OR in python is "or", not pipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use == to check equality

```
4 == 2*2
True
```

To use an if statement, conclude the line with a ':'

```
if line[5] in {'Tablespace Space Used (%)', 'Tablespace Free Space (MB)'}:
   do x
```

Comment: why are you using `in` still instead of `==`?

Comment: didn't see the OP's statement 'if line[5] is any of these I need to do some extra work.' will amend.

Comment: Sure, but why not use a membership test still?

Comment: Could you elucidate? My understanding is that '==' is a membership test. https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence

Comment: No, `==` tests for equality. `in` tests for membership. As in `something in ('valueA', 'valueB)` (which is implemented by testing for equality against each element in turn) or `something in {'valueA', 'valueB'} (which uses a hash table and equality testing for a more efficient membership test).

Comment: Thanks! I've amended that part.

Comment: The OP reported a syntax error when they tried a set literal, so perhaps they are using an older Python version. See the comments on my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You were missing the `:` at the end of your `if` statement.

However, you are using invalid syntax for your test too; it'll lead to a runtime error (`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'str'`). You want to create a tuple, or a set of strings to test against, not use `|`:

```
if line[5] in ("Tablespace Space Used (%)", "Tablespace Free Space (MB)"):
```

or

```
if line[5] in {"Tablespace Space Used (%)", "Tablespace Free Space (MB)"}:
```

The latter is technically more efficient, except if you are using Python 2 where the set isn't optimised into a constant the way the tuple would be in either version of the language. Using `{...}` to create a set requires Python 2.7 or newer.

Comment: @martinPeiters, I get this error: if line[5] in {"Tablespace Space Used (%)","Tablespace Free Space (MB)"}:
                                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @user1471980: What version of Python are you using? `{...}` for sets requires Python 2.7 or up.